# tool bar прозрачный но nav bar не прозрачный

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-toolbar, navigationbar

Всем привет, возник вопрос, как сделать toolbar в приложении прозрачным, НО если имеется nav bar, то он должен быть со стандартным непрозрачным фоном.Подобную штукку моно встретить в google play[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал вот такую функцию:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun initToolbarSettings(activity: Activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val window = activity.window
        //val background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.sign_in_gradient)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.transparent)
        window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.transparent)
        //window.setBackgroundDrawable(background)
    }
}
```

Думаю, вы можете взять ее за основу своих модификаций.

Comment: Не помогает почему-то, status bar не прозрачный

Comment: а вы цвет ставите прозрачный?

Comment: да, в том то и проблема, что как раз цвет меняется, но не прозрачность, хотя я ее ставлю через  Colors.argb()

Comment: window.statusBarColor = Color.argb(0,255,0,255)

Comment: попробуйте так: <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>, мб есть какой-то подводный камень. Какая версия android у вас?

Comment: 7.1.1 у меня, но я нашел немного не такой, но все таки работающий метод: window.addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)

Answer (score 0):

Решается довольно просто, данный способ убирает любые затемнения и отступы под статусбар. В результате можно поместить под статусбар любой контейнер со своим цветом или изображением.

**В onCreate()**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

**В styles.xml**

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
```